# Strip tags from Json Ajax Response

Tags: javascript

I am troubleshooting a page that makes ajax requests.Research indicated that i am receiving a "corrupt" json response in the format:

```
<pre>Array
  (
[sa_id] => 5
 )   </pre>{"result":true,"msg":"successful.","data":  
   {"fee":"100","balance":{"0":"12180"},"status":{"0":"0"}},"id":"5"}
```

I need to strip the response of

```
      <pre>Array
  (
[sa_id] => 5
  )
 </pre>
```

So that i can get valid json in the form of:

```
{"result":true,"msg":"successful.","data":   
{"fee":"100","balance":{"0":"12180"},"status":{"0":"0"}},"id":"5"}
```

I tried the following:

```
  newstring = resp.replace(/<pre[^>]*>([^<]*)<\/pre>/, "$1");
```

But it just removed the  tags and left the content between it.
How can i remove both the  tags and content between them so as to leave only the valid json response?.

Thanks

Comment: Are you in control of the server code? Wouldn't it be better to fix that instead? Looks like you've got a stray `print_r()` call somewhere in your server side php code.

Comment: Replace it with `""`, not `"$1"`. Also, fix the page that’s serving the invalid JSON instead of using this hack.

Comment: I am not..the ajax call is to a webservice that allows only registered ip addresses

Comment: It works Ryan o'Hara...if you put your comment as an answer i indicate it as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

You are matching a group inside the tag and replacing the entire tag and contents with only the contents. What you need to do is the following:

```
newstring = resp.replace(/<pre[^>]*>[^<]*<\/pre>/, "");
```

Check out the following [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sV3vW7/2) link to get clarity on the regex.